# which() - command on sequence doesn't find pattern

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

in Gnu R:

```
which(seq(0, 1600, 0.05) == 0.3) returns
integer(0)
```

but this:

```
which(round(seq(0, 1600, 0.05),2) == 0.3) returns
[1] 7
```

What happens with the `seq()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is essentially R FAQ 7.31 on comparisons between floats -- leading to the famous 'What every Computer Scientist should know about floating point numbers'.

In a nutshell, use `identical()` and other helper functions to compare relative to a small value \epsilon as perfect equality cannot be had with floating point types.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use `identical` here?  e.g. This also gives `integer(0)`: `which(sapply(seq(0, 1600, 0.05), identical, 0.3))`

Comment: Which is why I waffled and and said _and other helper functions_ :)  I wrote that on the train. Try this for size: `which(sapply(seq(0, 1, by=0.05), function(x) isTRUE(all.equal(x, 0.30))))`

Comment: Or simply test for an entry that is "close" to 0.3 with `which(abs(seq(0, 1600, 0.05) - 0.3)<.001)`

Comment: @StephanKolassa, that's _much_ faster.

Comment: And that is the usual way to do it in any programming language. With eps equal to sqrt of float precision.